# When I filter it clears my global search on jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using a plugin that I built for datatable for dropdown filter
and I'm using fnFilter for it.

The issue is when I search first let's say I searched for 'test' it
returns one row then when I filter, the filter doesn't do the filtering on
the one row I have on the table but instead it clears my global search
somehow.

Can someone please help me with this?

I think it just fnFilter clears search() on datatable but I don't want to
change fnFilter to search.

Comment: Please post at least a snippet of code to show what you've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have that problem when applying the filter to a column, if you don't provide the column to set the filter to the value passed to the filter will replace the search.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const dt = $('#example').dataTable({"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
    $("#filterbtn").on("click",x=>{
        dt.fnFilter( 'Gecko',0 );//column will not replace search
      dt.fnFilter( 'Camino',1 );//multiple filters are possible
    });
    $("#resetfilterbtn").on("click",x=>{
        dt.fnFilter( '',0 );//reset the filter (does not reset search)
      dt.fnFilter( '',1 );
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2520/).

In the jsfiddle example search for `3+` and get 5 rows, then press filter button and get 1 row, then press reset filter button and get 5 rows again.

If you press filter button you'll get 2 rows, no matter what you search you will not get more than 2 rows (search does not reset the filter)

Comment: thank u soo much for help, i do have column index number specified on my filter. But i have a question what if i have search on columns as well ?  so lets say i have fnFilter and am using global serach and search for specific column, by doing the stuff you mentioned would it still work even if i have serach per column as well?